# Postgres query runs 1000X slower when combined with UNION ALL than when queries run separate

Tags: postgresql, performance, union-all, explain

I have two queries that when run separately, each take 1-10 seconds to execute. When I combine their results with `UNION ALL`, the execution time jumps up to 4500 seconds (*over 1 hour*)!

I have run the long query with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and it appears to iterate over `man_jour_tracking` 1.6B times - even though that table is only ~11k lines long. It looks to be creating `man_jour_tracking` on each join -- but only when the UNION is present, not when run on it's own. [Explain Analyze Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBGlw.png)

I do not know if it has to do with the `json_object` data type. But somehow the planner is not handling this correctly since they execute on their own and all records will be unique.

(I have taken out a variety of select columns to shorten the query since they are not relevant). PostgreSQL 13.7

**Running this query alone (first SELECT from union query) take ~5 seconds.**

```
WITH most_recent_journum as (
    SELECT
        max(journal_number) as journum,
        max(journal_date) as jourdate,
        max(source_type)
    FROM journal
    GROUP BY source_id
),

man_jour_tracking as (
    SELECT
        json_object(Array_agg(tracking_category.name), array_agg(option)) as tracking,
        manual_journal_line_id,
        manual_journal_id
    FROM
        manual_journal_line_has_tracking_category line_tracking
        LEFT JOIN tracking_category on line_tracking.tracking_category_id = tracking_category.tracking_category_id
    GROUP BY manual_journal_line_id, manual_journal_id
)

SELECT
    journal.journal_id as journal_id,
    journal.journal_number as journal_number,
    gross_amount as gross_amount,
    line.account_code as account_code,
    line.account_name as account_name,
    line.account_type as account_type,
    line.description as description,
    manual_journal.status as status,
    trim('"' FROM (man_jour_tracking.tracking -> 'Tracking')::text) as tracking,
    trim('"' FROM (man_jour_tracking.tracking -> 'Events Tracking')::text) as events_tracking,
    NULL as invoice_number,
    NULL as contact_name,
    manual_journal.narration as source_description
FROM journal
    LEFT JOIN journal_line line on line.journal_id = journal.journal_id
    LEFT JOIN manual_journal ON journal.source_id = manual_journal.manual_journal_id
    LEFT JOIN manual_journal_line manual_line ON
        manual_line.manual_journal_id = manual_journal.manual_journal_id AND line.account_code = manual_line.account_code AND line.description = manual_line.description AND line.gross_amount = manual_line.line_amount
    LEFT JOIN 
        man_jour_tracking ON
        manual_journal.manual_journal_id = man_jour_tracking.manual_journal_id AND man_jour_tracking.manual_journal_line_id::int = manual_line.line
WHERE
    journal.source_type = 'MANJOURNAL' AND
    journal.journal_number in (select journum from most_recent_journum) AND
    journal.journal_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' >= '2022-10-01'::date AND journal_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' < '2023-01-01'::date AND
    line.journal_line_id is not null AND
    line.account_code <> '2650' AND
    manual_journal.status = 'POSTED'
```

**Running this query alone (second SELECT from union query) takes ~5 seconds**

```
WITH most_recent_journum as (
    SELECT
        max(journal_number) as journum,
        max(journal_date) as jourdate,
        max(source_type)
    FROM journal
    GROUP BY source_id
),

man_jour_tracking as (
    SELECT
        json_object(Array_agg(tracking_category.name), array_agg(option)) as tracking,
        manual_journal_line_id,
        manual_journal_id
    FROM
        manual_journal_line_has_tracking_category line_tracking
        LEFT JOIN tracking_category on line_tracking.tracking_category_id = tracking_category.tracking_category_id
    GROUP BY manual_journal_line_id, manual_journal_id
)

SELECT
    journal.journal_id as journal_id,
    journal.journal_number as journal_number,
    NULL::int as source_line,
    gross_amount as gross_amount,
    line.account_code as account_code,
    line.account_name as account_name,
    line.account_type as account_type,
    line.description as description,
    invoice.status as status,
    NULL as tracking,
    NULL as events_tracking,
    invoice.invoice_number,
    contact.name as contact_name,
    NULL as source_description
FROM journal
    LEFT JOIN journal_line line on line.journal_id = journal.journal_id 
    LEFT JOIN invoice ON journal.source_id = invoice.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN contact on invoice.contact_id = contact.contact_id
WHERE
    journal.source_type in ('ACCPAY', 'ACCREC') AND
    journal.journal_number in (select journum from most_recent_journum) AND
    journal.journal_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' >= '2022-10-01'::date AND journal_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' < '2023-01-01'::date AND
    line.journal_line_id is not null AND
    invoice.status not in ('VOIDED', 'DELETED')
```

**But when you combine them together, the query takes over 1 hour.**

```
WITH most_recent_journum as (
    SELECT
        max(journal_number) as journum,
        max(journal_date) as jourdate,
        max(source_type)
    FROM journal
    GROUP BY source_id
),

man_jour_tracking as (
    SELECT
        json_object(Array_agg(tracking_category.name), array_agg(option)) as tracking,
        manual_journal_line_id,
        manual_journal_id
    FROM
        manual_journal_line_has_tracking_category line_tracking
        LEFT JOIN tracking_category on line_tracking.tracking_category_id = tracking_category.tracking_category_id
    GROUP BY manual_journal_line_id, manual_journal_id
)

SELECT
    journal.journal_id as journal_id,
    journal.journal_number as journal_number,
    gross_amount as gross_amount,
    line.account_code as account_code,
    line.account_name as account_name,
    line.account_type as account_type,
    line.description as description,
    manual_journal.status as status,
    trim('"' FROM (man_jour_tracking.tracking -> 'Tracking')::text) as tracking,
    trim('"' FROM (man_jour_tracking.tracking -> 'Events Tracking')::text) as events_tracking,
    NULL as invoice_number,
    NULL as contact_name,
    manual_journal.narration as source_description
FROM journal
    LEFT JOIN journal_line line on line.journal_id = journal.journal_id
    LEFT JOIN manual_journal ON journal.source_id = manual_journal.manual_journal_id
    LEFT JOIN manual_journal_line manual_line ON
        manual_line.manual_journal_id = manual_journal.manual_journal_id AND line.account_code = manual_line.account_code AND line.description = manual_line.description AND line.gross_amount = manual_line.line_amount
    LEFT JOIN 
        man_jour_tracking ON
        manual_journal.manual_journal_id = man_jour_tracking.manual_journal_id AND man_jour_tracking.manual_journal_line_id::int = manual_line.line
WHERE
    journal.source_type = 'MANJOURNAL' AND
    journal.journal_number in (select journum from most_recent_journum) AND
    journal.journal_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' >= '2022-10-01'::date AND journal_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' < '2023-01-01'::date AND
    line.journal_line_id is not null AND
    line.account_code <> '2650' AND
    manual_journal.status = 'POSTED'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    journal.journal_id as journal_id,
    journal.journal_number as journal_number,
    NULL::int as source_line,
    gross_amount as gross_amount,
    line.account_code as account_code,
    line.account_name as account_name,
    line.account_type as account_type,
    line.description as description,
    invoice.status as status,
    NULL as tracking,
    NULL as events_tracking,
    invoice.invoice_number,
    contact.name as contact_name,
    NULL as source_description
FROM journal
    LEFT JOIN journal_line line on line.journal_id = journal.journal_id 
    LEFT JOIN invoice ON journal.source_id = invoice.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN contact on invoice.contact_id = contact.contact_id
WHERE
    journal.source_type in ('ACCPAY', 'ACCREC') AND
    journal.journal_number in (select journum from most_recent_journum) AND
    journal.journal_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' >= '2022-10-01'::date AND journal_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' < '2023-01-01'::date AND
    line.journal_line_id is not null AND
    invoice.status not in ('VOIDED', 'DELETED')
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Things I have tried:

1. Separated `man_jour_tracking` out from a CTE into a temp table (`CREATE TEMP TABLE man_jour_tracking`) and created an index (`CREATE INDEX idx_man_jour_tracking ON man_jour_tracking (manual_journal_id, manual_journal_line_id)`) in hopes of speeding up the join or forcing the planner to cache the joined table. No faster.
2. Switched order of SELECT statements within union
3. Replacing `UNION ALL` with `UNION` - no help.
4. Even remove `man_jour_tracking` CTE entirely and still takes ages longer when combined than when separate.

**EDIT - SOLVED**
Thanks to @jjanes, creating the CTE's with `as NOT MATERIALIZED` fixed it! I do think it's a bit counter-intuitive because you would want the CTE cached, however perhaps it removes a critical index that substantially slows down the joins. Another post [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257014/are-there-side-effects-to-postgres-12s-not-materialized-directive) for more context.

Comment: Execution plans are better shared as formatted text, generated using `explain (analyze, buffers) ...` the graphical display simply hides too many important details. If it's to big to be included in the question, you can share it e.g. through https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: Here is the full explain text: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Zh2s

Comment: Your plan references a CTE "constants", but no such CTE exists in your question.  Since you showed us some amended query, show the plan for the amended query.

Comment: What happens if you do `WITH most_recent_journum as NOT MATERIALIZED (...`?

Comment: @jjanes `NOT MATERIALIZED` did it!! It brought the runtime down to under 20 seconds.

"constants" was a very brief CTE where it just kept constants to be referenced throughout the query (`SELECT '2022-10-01'::date as start_date, '2023-01-01'::date as end_date`) and non-material in terms of runtime.

Comment: @jjanes any idea why NOT MATERIALIZED fixes it? Wouldn't you want the CTE cached so that it does not need to be created with each iteration? I would have thought the problem was that it wasn't materialized in the first place, hence the 1.6B rows recreated with each iteration.

Comment: That is odd to me, but without a plan which matches the query or a query which matches the plan, there is no way to investigate it.